# Pixel 7 USB Driver not recognized on Windows 11

Tags: android, usb

The Pixel 7 device, when set to Developer Mode and connected to a Windows 11 machine, will not recognize to allow debugging.  I have tried all the different drivers and recommendations on other sites to no avail.

The device recognizes that it is connected. And on other machines, it is recognized under Device Manager, but my main dev machine will not see it.  The difference with my main dev machine is I have many other devices that I test with as well.  Surface Duo, Samsung, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this by using a USB-A to USB-C cable.  It appears the drivers are somehow disconnected from USB-C to USB-C with Pixel devices at times.  It must be a conflict that isn't an issue with the USB-A drivers.

I hope this helps other devs - it took 4 hours out of my day trying all the other sites' recommendations.